# Wamp - MySQL service stops for Innodb tables

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb

MySQL service was running fine but once I tried to create a new InnoDb table, always receive this:

```
#2006 error. Mysql gone away.
```

I installed even new wamp but still same issue. I increased max_allowed_packet to 200MB but still same issue.

```
2016-03-01 18:59:40 11872 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\newdb\answer.ibd: 'open' returned OS error 1379. Cannot continue operation
2016-03-01 19:00:16 2eb8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-03-01 19:00:16 11960 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-03-01 19:00:26 2eb8  InnoDB: Operating system error number 1179 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
 InnoDB: Operation open to file os\os0file.cc and at line 2041
2016-03-01 19:00:26 11960 [ERROR] InnoDB: File G:\Xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 1379. Cannot continue operation
```

Comment: What is in mysqld.err ?

Comment: Was it just a `CREATE`?  Or was it `CREATE ... SELECT from huge table`?  Please give more details.

Comment: Just when i try to create an INNODB table. sometimes it stucks with characterset utf8. Sometimes with combined primary key.

Comment: I even installed xampp and mysql server seperatly but always this issue occurs. can anybody solve this issue?